# Error in version display SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, versioning

I am getting below error when I try to see the version of an item.

```
Error 
Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: a3c31e7a-2490-49f4-9846-d07f8697d9bc 

Date and Time: 6/11/2012 11:13:54 AM
```

I am creating item in this list using copy item action of SP designer workflow.
Earlier it was working, I was able to see the versions, now its showing error. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that is fixed in Feb 2012 CU. Refer the URL:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/b55a7370-cdcb-446a-8d89-9adba1f3df2a